# Regular expression: dot with exclusion includes excluded char

Tags: php, regex

Following example:

```
    $text = <<<END
some text

q 1
some next line

q 2 test
exptra line
END;

    $text   = trim($text);
    if (preg_match_all("/\nQ\s+\d+.[^\n]*\n/isU", $text, $match)) {
        print_r($match);
        echo "OK";
    } else {
        echo "FAIL";
    }
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
q 1
some next line

            [1] => 
q 2 test

        )

)
OK
```

Please make a note that new line in example for `$text` consist only of one `\n`.

For some reason `.[^\n]*` includes new line symbol even if it is stated as exclude. It happens only if new line is the only symbol to match with this part of expression (`\n` goes just after 1), and star (`*`), which should mean any number of characters including none/optional does not play here correctly.

As I need to match both cases, what can be done in that case?

Expected output, to match both lines starting with `q N` but without following line:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
q 1 

            [1] => 
q 2 test

        )

)
```

The example above is simplified. Matched string can contain newlines characters, but not in the specified place. Actually I tested `.` with other symbols and it works same. If the only char is left for dot is the one which stated as exclude - it still includes it:

```
    $text = <<<END
some text

q 1e
some next line

q 2 test
exptra line
END;

    $text   = trim($text);
    if (preg_match_all("/Q\s+\d+.[^e]*/iU", $text, $match)) {
        print_r($match);
        echo "OK";
    } else {
        echo "FAIL";
    }
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => q 1e
            [1] => q 2 
        )

)
```

Comment: `.` matches `\n` because you have `s` flag. `[^\n]*`matches **zero** or more non-LFs, so it does not restrict the `.` here. What do you expect  to get here?

Comment: Try `preg_match_all('~^Q\h+\d.*~im', $text, $matches)`. See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/K6lafk/2).

Comment: Added expected output. From `s` modifiers documentation `A negative class such as [^a] always matches a newline character`, so it should not really matter if the `s` modifier is in place or not for this case. `\n` stated as "exclude" char and should not be included like it is for second case.

Comment: `s` flag modifies the behavior of `.`, not `[^a]`, you got confused with the docs here.

Comment: I mean that `.[^a]` according to documentation includes newline character anyway, regardless of whether `s` is place or not.

Comment: I doubt that is relevant here anyway. You need to match a line, so `.` without any flags does the job perfectly. See my answer below.

Comment: BTW, you have not inidicated what output you expect for the second sample input.

Answer (score 1):

Modifier `s` toggles the behaviour of the `.`. Because you included it the `.` will match `\n`.

A small demo:

```
$patterns = [
  '(.*)', '(.*)s', '([^\\n]*)'
];

foreach ($patterns as $pattern) {
    preg_match($pattern, "foo\nbar", $match);
    echo $pattern, ': "', $match[0], "\"\n";
}
```

Output:

```
(.*): "foo"
(.*)s: "foo
bar"
([^\n]*): "foo"
```

Modifier `m` would be more appropriate in your case. It changes the behaviour of `^` and `$` to match line (and not just string) start/end.

```
$pattern = '(
  ^q   # letter q or Q at line start (with modifier m)
  \\s+  # at least one whitespace 
  (?<number>\\d+) # string of digits - named group "number"
  (?<label>[^\\n]*) # any character except "\n" (without modifier s) - named group "label"
)xmi';

if (preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $match, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
    print_r($match);
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => q 1
            [number] => 1
            [1] => 1
            [label] => 
            [2] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => q 2 test
            [number] => 2
            [1] => 2
            [label] =>  test
            [2] =>  test
        )

)
```

Modifier `x` enables "extended syntax". It allows to format and document the pattern.

I suggest using named groups for the results. It makes the code more readable and robust. `PREG_SET_ORDER` puts the data for each match into a set.

Answer (score 0):

Your `/Q\s+\d+.[^e]*/iU` regex contains a `U` (PCRE_UNGREEDY) flag that swaps greediness of the quantifiers, and is equal to `/Q\s+?\d+?.[^e]*?/i` pattern. `/Q\s+?\d+?.[^e]*?/i` matches `q` or `Q`, then any one or more but as few as possible whitespace chars, then one or more but as few as possible digits, and then any char (other than a line break char if `s` flag is omitted) and then - look - *any zero or more chars other than `e` **as few as possible*** (i.e. it does not match any text, as it does not have to).

You can use

```php
<?php

$text = <<<END
some text

q 1
some next line

q 2 test
exptra line
END;

if (preg_match_all('~^Q\h+\d.*~im', $text, $match)) {
    print_r($match);
    echo "OK";
} else {
    echo "FAIL";
}
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/Vb9S9). Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => q 1
            [1] => q 2 test
        )

)
OK
```

*Pattern details*:

- `^` - start of a line (due to the `m` flag)
- `Q` - `Q` or `q` (due to the `i` flag)
- `\h+` - one or more horizontal whitespaces
- `\d` - a digit
- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars (as I am not using `s` flag) as many as possible (i.e. the rest of the line).

Comment: Sorry, cannot accept the answer. The example above is simplified. Matched string can contain newlines characters, but not in the specified place. Actually I tested `.` with other symbols and it works same. If the only char is left for dot is the one which stated as exclude - it still includes it. See added example.

Comment: @Index If you explain your pattern requirements in plain English, it would be much easier to provide you with a 100% working solution. Your examples do not clear out what you actually want to achieve. Please look at my pattern details and compile a set of requirements using a similar style.

Comment: @Index I will add an exaplanation why you get those matches, maybe it will give you a hint.